# Multisite in subfolder - How to make new sites to be in same level subfolders as the main site

Tags: multisite, directory

I have following situation. I have a WP Multisite installed in subdirectory:

```
my-domain.com/subfolder/wp-multisite-root
```

Now normally next sites added would be created like that

```
my-domain.com/subfolder/wp-multisite-root
my-domain.com/subfolder/wp-multisite-root/site1
my-domain.com/subfolder/wp-multisite-root/site2
my-domain.com/subfolder/wp-multisite-root/site3
```

Is there any way to have it created like this?

```
my-domain.com/subfolder/wp-multisite-root
my-domain.com/subfolder/site1
my-domain.com/subfolder/site2
my-domain.com/subfolder/site3
```

There is one more trick. my-domain.com/subfolder/ contains another non wordpress application.

Comment: What *non wp application* means? What .htaccess / slug conflicts do you have?

Answer (score 7):

After these years I hope this will still answer your question...

I think I've got the situation working you want.
Allthough I don't have the Wordpress installation in '/subfolder/', but I've a installation 'in subdirectory' per language, and on the same level:

```
 my-domain.com/nl/ -> this is primary installation, site id = 1 
 my-domain.com/en/ -> this is the first site created by multistie, site id = 2
 my-domain.com/de/ -> this is the second site created by multistie, site id = 3
```

It requires a bit 'hacking' in the database, but it's very easy.

**Step 1:**
Make sure your multisite 'root' installation is working as intended in it's subdirectory. In my case I got the following in 'wp-config.php':

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false); // allow sub-directory install (true for subdomain install)
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'my-domain.com/subfolder');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wp-multisite-root/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

(well in reality I don't have '/subfolder' :) )

**Step 2:**
Now create you're first new site through multisite in a subfolder.
When entering the foldername 'site2', Wordpress tells you it will be created as:
my-domain.com/subfolder/wp-multisite-root/site2
That's correct, we will remove the 'wp-multisite-root' folder manually t

**Step 3:**
Open up phpMyAdmin/directAdmin
In the table `wp_blogs` edit the entry of you're newly created site.
We will have to modify the `path` of it.
It can be done with the following query:

```
UPDATE `wp_blogs` SET `path` = '/site2/' WHERE `wp_blogs`.`path` = '/wp-multisite-root/site2/';
```

Change domain name and site name accordingly.
Also look for the site id mentioned there. If its the first extra site created it will be ID 2 as in my intro.

**Step 4:**
Look into the table `wp_<SITEID>_options`.
In our case with Site ID 2, it will be `wp_2_options`.
There we will have to change the `option_value` where the `option_name` is 'siteurl' and 'home'. It can be done by running following queries:

```
UPDATE `wp_2_options` SET `option_value` = 'my-domain.com/subfolder/site2/' WHERE `option_name` = 'siteurl';
UPDATE `wp_2_options` SET `option_value` = 'my-domain.com/subfolder/site2/' WHERE `option_name` = 'home';
```

Again, change the domain and folder name accordingly.
You'll note that we remove 'wp-multisite-root' from the url there, so site2 will be on the same level as `wp-multisite-root'.

**Step 5:**
Refresh wp-admin and your site(s) will be listed as you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Piemol's answer is great and worked for me. However, I was unable to log into any of my sites except the main site. Upon inspecting my cookies, I discovered WordPress was making a cookie for only my main site and not the other subdirectories. To use OP's example, it was making a cookie for `/subfolder/wp-multisite-root`, which `/subfolder/site1` could not use.

I dug through WordPress core to see what I needed to fix, and I ended up adding this code to my custom plugin to fix the paths used for the cookies:

```
define('COOKIEPATH', '/subfolder/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/subfolder/');
```

In my case, my site structure is actually like Piemol's, so I fixed my cookie paths to be the root:

```
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to make `my-domain/subfolder/` the WordPress install directory and base URL, then enable multisite configured to use subdirectories.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add my-domain/subfolder/ contains an application.

Comment: Maybe move the application?

Comment: @ChipBennett would that override any of the current site configurations?

Comment: How to make install directory into subfolder?

Answer (score -1):

I've been trying to do a similar thing, and from everything I've discovered so far I think the answer is no, this isn't currently possible :(