# How to use the same "wp_posts" table for different subdirectories in the same DB?

Tags: multisite, directory

I have a WP multisite with many subdirectories. I have the main site like *mainsite.com* and a table "wp_posts"

I have some subdirectories like *mainsite.com/sub1*, *mainsite.com/sub2*, and their tables like "wp_2_posts", "wp_3_posts"

I need that each subdirectory ignore their own "wp_n_posts" table and work with *wp_posts*

Comment: Fundamentally changing the database table structure is likely to cause a significant amount of difficulty and headaches. What have you tried so far? And what is the reason you are trying to put all subsites' posts into the one `wp_posts` table? There may be a better way to achieve your ultimate goal, but if you share why or how you're planning to use the combined post data, it will be easier for others to understand and offer suggestions. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multisite in subfolder - How to make new sites to be in same level subfolders as the main site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119493/multisite-in-subfolder-how-to-make-new-sites-to-be-in-same-level-subfolders-as)